# Use Python Virtual Environment in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, virtual-environment

I'm often working on a python project where I start the project with a virtual environment and a Jupyter notebook. I start adding libraries to the virtual environment as I experiment in the Jupyter notebook. The problem is that if I run

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

at the end of my project that file will include the libraries for jupyter in my virtual environment. Is there some way I can run a Jupyter notebook but use a kernel associated with another virtual environment?

I know I could remove the jupyter related requirements from what is frozen but that seems like a hack. I can't see any way to avoid installing at least ipykernel in the target virtual environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Make a new directory under the Jupyter kernels directory. If you do not know where to find it, please check here (https://jupyter-client.readthedocs.io/en/stable/kernels.html).
2. Create a `kernel.json` file with the following:

```
{
 "argv": [ "/path-to-env/myenv/bin/python", "-m", "ipykernel",
          "-f", "{connection_file}"],
 "display_name": "myenv",
 "language": "python"
}
```

3. That's it! Now you can run `jupyter notebook` and be able to see a kernel that uses your virtual environment.

Here's a blog that explains it in more detail: https://www.alfredo.motta.name/create-isolated-jupyter-ipython-kernels-with-pyenv-and-virtualenv/

Comment: `python -m ipykernel install --user --name myenv --display-name "Python (myenv)"` also works.

Answer (score 0):

## Step 1: Create a Python 3 Virtual Environment

- Conda: Absent

```bash
virtualenv -p python3 <env name>
```

- Conda: Present and have sufficient disk space

```bash
conda create -n <env name> python==<version> -y
```

- Conda: Present and optimized disk space

```bash
conda create -prefix <./path/to/env_name> python==`<version>` -y
```

## Step 2: Activate the Virtual Environment

- Conda: Absent and Linux system

```bash
source <env name>/bin/activate
```

- Conda: Absent and Windows system

```bash
my-python3-env\Scripts\activate
```

- Conda: Present

```bash
conda activate <`env name` or `./path/to/env_name`>
```

## Step 3: Install the IPython Kernel Package

```bash
pip install ipykernel
pip install notebook
```

## Step 4: Register the Kernel with Jupyter

```bash
python -m ipykernel install --user --name=<env name>
```

## Rename a jupyter notebook kernel display name

```bash
jupyter kernelspec list
```

The above command will provide you a list of the installed Kernels, something like:

```bash
Available kernels:
  python2          /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ipykernel/resources
  redisworkshop    /Users/tague/Library/Jupyter/kernels/RedisWorkshop
  bash             /Users/tague/Library/Jupyter/kernels/bash
```

The `display name` for a kernel is found in the **kernel.json** file in the corresponding directory for the kernel.
Edit the `display_name` property in the **kernel.json** file and it will change the display name next time you start Jupyter.